# Output of wget (to CouchDB) as array used in for-loop

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, for-loop, wget

I try to use the output of wget to build an array I can use for a for loop:

```
RESULT="`wget -qO- http://myCouchDBServer.com:5984/_all_dbs`"
echo $RESULT
```

What I get is something like:

```
["_replicator","_users","mydb1","mydb2","mydb3","mydb4","mydb5"]
```

At the moment I loop through an array i wrote manually:

```
databases=(mydb1 mydb2 mydb2)

for var in "${databases[@]}"
do
#  echo "${var}"
  # do something on $var
    filename="${var}_$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S).json"
    echo $filename
 bash couchdb-backup.sh -b -H myHostIP_Adress -d ${var} -f $filename -u myUsername -p myPassword

done
```

Now I would like to use the response from wget and build an array from this response which I can use for my for-loop.

I tried

```
RESULT2= echo "$RESULT" | sed 's/\(\[\|\]\)//g'
```

to get rid of the square brackets and tried to build an array 
but there is no output and therefore also no loop running...

```
STR_ARRAY=(`echo $RESULT2 | tr "," "\n"`)
for x in "${STR_ARRAY[@]}"
do
echo "&gt; [$x]"
done
```

Any idea how to get a step further?

PS: 
(my couchdb is only reachable through intranet but I found an url for testing: http://example.iriscouch.com/_all_dbs )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since couch is spitting out JSON, you'll want to process it with a JSON parser. For example, `jq`:

```
echo '["_replicator","_users","mydb1","mydb2","mydb3","mydb4","mydb5"]' | jq -r '.[]|.'
```

```
_replicator
_users
mydb1
mydb2
mydb3
mydb4
mydb5
```

So, you could do this:

```
mapfile -t all_dbs < <(
    wget -qO- http://myCouchDBServer.com:5984/_all_dbs | jq -r '.[]|.'
)
for db in "${all_dbs[@]}"; do ...; done
```

Comment: thanks.just needed to realize that i had to install qj ( https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ ) to get it running but now it works perfectly.